# Understanding degrees of freedom for the chi-square component of the t-distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

In looking at the t-distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\bar{x}-\mu)/S$, I can see that this equates to the following:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{x}-\mu)}{S} = \frac{(\bar{x}-\mu)}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{(\bar{x}-\mu)}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{n}}} \sim \frac{N(0,1)}{\sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{n}}} \sim t_n$$

I am curious about how the Chi-square component of this equates to the sample variance for the given degrees of freedom. From my understanding, the sample variance is determined by:

$$S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}{\sqrt{n-1}} \sim \frac{\chi^2}{\sqrt{n-1}}$$

...and unless I'm mistaken this distribution is modified by $v = n-1$ degrees of freedom to adjust for bias. What is confusing to me is why the t-distrubution above does not also use $n-1$?

My understanding of the t-distribution is that the chi component in the denominator is an increasingly normal distribution about 1 (as $v$ increases), for adjusting the normal distribution of the mean to account for sampling differences (since it is based on the standard error of the mean), so shouldn't this denominator always be adjusted to distribute about 1? By this argument, the t-distribution should have $S/\sqrt{n-1}$ in the denominator. Why is this not the case? As-is, the denominator's distribution appears to centralize at less than 1 for low values of n.

Comment: The formula / distribution you have for the sample variance are not correct.  It should be $S^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X})^2 / (n - 1)$, which is actually distributed $\sigma^2 \chi^2_{n - 1} / (n - 1)$.

Comment: Man...I spend all this time freaking out about not understanding things, only to find some ridiculous mistake like that. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 
$$(n-1){S_n^2/\sigma^2}\sim\chi_{n-1}^2$$

Student-t is the ratio of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and square root of $\chi^2$ divided by its d.f.

$$t=\frac{\frac{\bar X_n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)S_n^2/\sigma^2}{n-1}}}=\frac{\bar X_n-\mu}{S_n/\sqrt{n}}\sim t_{n-1}$$

with $n-1$ d.f.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Despite the mistake I made above, I found the hinging component of $S^2 \sim \sigma^2 \frac{\chi_{n-1}^2}{n-1}$, which converts the degrees of freedom from relating to the population through $\sigma$ to the sample through $S$. However, your equation there is a far more concise way of showing this. Thanks! :)